# Venn Diagram Problem

Tags: combinatorics

Problem: There are $50$ people in a room. $28$ are male, and $32$ are under the age of $30$. Twelve are males under the age of $30$. How many women over the age of $30$ are in the group?

(A) $2$

(B) $3$

(C) $4$

(D) $5$

(E) $6$

The correct answer is (A). The issue I have with this question is the wording, which I believe to be incorrect. The way I solved this problem is that I set up a Venn diagram with the left circle called "male" and the right circle called "under the age of $30$". After calculating the left space and right space ($16$ and $20$ respectively) based on the given shared space $(12)$, I subtracted. $50-(16+12+20)=2$. Since the only category left is the number of females whose age is either over or equal to $30$, then $2$ females are either over or equal to $30$. However, the question asks how many females are over $30$. But they are leaving out the equal to so the wording is wrong isn't it?

Comment: So your issue is what about the females who are exactly $30$?

Comment: Being $30$ you are still "over the age of $30$". There is exactly one moment in your life time where your birth is exactly $30$ years ago.

Answer (score 0):

There is $22$ womens and $20$ of them are under $30$ so ...

Comment: ... so 2 of the women are aged 30 or over, which is probably what the question was intended to be, but it actually asks for the number of women *over* the age of 30, which could mean age $> 30$

Comment: Yes, I agree ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes your approach and answer is correct. And I also thinks that there is some problem in wording. It may be possible that $30$ is included in the word "under the age of $30$". But it should be distinctly mentioned.